# Deleting profile account of a business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a personal account and later I created a business page linked to it.

I want to keep only the business/fan page and delete the account (profile) created earlier. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Someone (a flesh-and-blood person) needs to own the business/fan page.   If you don't want to be that someone any more, then you need to find someone else who is going to take on the role.

- They need to "Like" the page.
- Then you use your current personal profile to edit the Page and make
  them an administrator.
- And lastly they use their personal profile to remove you from the
  page administrators.

On the other hand, if you still want to be the flesh-and-blood person who administers the page, but you just don't want to use Facebook youself any more then just:

- Unfriend all your current friends
- Change your personal settings to Private / Me-only / whatever FB is
  calling it this week
- Don't post anything to your profile, or use any features except the
  business-page.